# Getting newest timestamp mysql

Tags: mysql

Ok, so I have a table which records in a column called 'time' the time that it was updated. This column records in standard MySQL datetime format.

I have the following query which picks out the newest date:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DATE(time) = ( SELECT MAX(DATE(time))FROM table1 )
```

and I have another query which picks out the latest time:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE TIME(time) = ( SELECT MAX(TIME(time))FROM table1 )
```

What I need is one that does both the date and the time to give me the most recently updated record.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't really need `MAX()` here but it's worth noting that you can do `MAX(time)` directly. No need to split date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 order by time desc limit 1
```

Recommend not using time as a column name because it is a reserved word in MySQL and will cause problems and/or confusion.

Also, MySQL can maintain automatically the datetime that a record was last updated. Declare a column as timestamp instead of datetime to see how this works.

Comment: just `limit 1` will suffice

Comment: Time is not a reserved word in MySQL, but I agree that it can cause confusion.

Comment: @Strawberry Time is a reserved keyword but it is permitted to be used without backtick just like date. `:)`

Comment: [MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Changed the column title to tstamp. More appropriate anyway. Query worked a treat, marked as answer. Thanks!

Comment: JW - we clearly understand very different definitions of the term 'reserved'" !! It IS a keyword but it IS explicitly NOT reserved. :-)